# How to select a node from an xml created by json-to-xml()

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am trying to get an element from a JSON after converting it to XML.

Working example: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJf/1

In this example, it is parsed successfully but when I want to select a node with the code below I could not bring the data I need.

`<xsl:copy-of select="json-to-xml(root)//map[@key='identifier']"/>`

JSON:

```
<root><![CDATA[{
            "identifier": {
                "use": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"> </div>"
                }
        }]]></root>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="json-to-xml(root)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My desired output is this:

```
   <map key="identifier">
      <string key="use">&lt;div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt; &lt;/div&gt;</string>
   </map>
```

or this

```
 <string key="use">&lt;div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt; &lt;/div&gt;</string>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML that is being generated by `json-to-xml` has a default namespace

```
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
  <map key="identifier">
    <string key="use">&lt;div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt; &lt;/div&gt; 
    </string>
  </map>
</map>
```

Your XSLT is looking for a `map` in no namespace. So, you will have to adjust the xpath to cope with any namespace, but also use `xsl:apply-templates` so you can have a template that removes the namespace from the elements.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(root)//*:map[@key='identifier']"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hopefully, Martin Honnen will stop by soon, and point out a much better way of doing this... ;)

Comment: Thanks, it is working but honestly I did not understand the logic :) Is there an easy way to use it just  with `json-to-xml(root)//map[@key='identifier']`. Maybe with namespace or something I don't know.

Comment: @rdonuk, of course you can use `json-to-xml(.)//map[@key='identifier']` to select the element if you declare `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"`, so there is a way to shorten your XPath expression (although given your XML is in no namespace you need to take care where to put the declaration: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJf/2). But if you want an output without that namespace then you have to run the result of `json-to-xml` through some templates stripping the namespace, as Tim has shown.

Comment: @MartinHonnen One last question; if I put that namespace declaration to the top, it is printing the json as it is. But your example is working very well of course. What is the reason for that? Of course, I am not saying to you that explain to me the all namespace concept :) maybe you can give me some links to understand this. Because as you guess I don't want to put that declaration each time I select a node. My original JSON is too long and I will do a lot of operations on that.

Comment: The `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` is in scope for the element you put it on and any descendants, unless overriden. If you put it on the root element of the stylesheet then it applies to `match="root"` as well and does not match your input as that is in no namespace and not in the XPath functions namespace. So you will need to find some way to structure your code for that, either work with explict namespaces prefixes e.g. `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` and e.g `fn:map` or `fn:string` or use the namespace wildcard `*:map` or `*:string`.

Comment: If you want to get familiar with XPath and XSLT, there are tutorials and books available, for instance a PDF copy of "Practical Transformation Using XSLT and XPath" by G. Ken Holman is available at https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm and treats `xpath-default-namespace` in chapter 3, section 2.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much sir, I will take a look. For now, using `xmlns:fn` is pretty ok for me.